# How do I add a design-time description to a property implemented through an extender provider?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I know that I can add a design-time Designer description to a custom control's property by doing this:

```
<Category("Data"), Description("This describes this awesome property")>
Public Property Foo As Boolean
...
End Property
```

What I want to do is the exact same thing, but to properties that my **extender provider** component is providing other controls on my form with, so that when I click on the property's value field, for example, I would see the description I wrote for it. Searched a lot for an answer but had no success so far. Would I have to add something to my getter and setter methods for the property?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Would I have to add something to my getter and setter methods for the property?`

Yes.  Add the `DescriptionAttribute` to the `Get[PropertyName]` method.  The same goes for any other Attributes (they dont seem to work on the `Set`... counterpart).

```
<Category("ListContolExtender"), DisplayName("DisplayMode"),
Description("My very clever description")>
Public Function GetDisplayMode(ctl As Control) As ItemDisplays
    If extData.ContainsKey(ctl) Then
        Return extData(ctl).DispMode
    Else
        Return ItemDisplays.Enabled
    End If
End Function


Public Sub SetDisplayMode(ctl As Control, v As ItemDisplays)
    If extData.ContainsKey(ctl) Then
        extData(ctl).DispMode = v
    Else
        Dim e As New ExtenderData
        e.DispMode = v
        extData.Add(ctl, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

The `DisplayNameattribute` hides all the `DisplayMode on ListBoxExtender` verbiage

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Very straight forward, after all!